# Exception in JasperPHP.php line 178: Your report has an error and couldn't be processed

Tags: php, laravel-5, jasper-reports

If you have some time to replay to me. 
I try to use JasperPHP in Laravel 5 but can't. I make sample report with static text:
[image: test report]
But when I publish it and start with Laravel with that code:

```
    $output = public_path() . '/report/Test';
    $ext = "pdf";
    $jasper = JasperPHP::compile(
        public_path() . '/reports/Test.jasper',
        true
    )->execute();

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.time().'Test.'.$ext);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($output.'.'.$ext));
    flush();
    readfile($output.'.'.$ext);
    unlink($output.'.'.$ext); // deletes the temporary file
```

And Laravel gives me an error:

Exception in JasperPHP.php line 178: Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console.

Can you help me? What I do wrong? I would like to generate pdf file for that report and send it to client.

Also one more question. How to send param to report?

The same problem I have when try with real report with datasets

When I change it with:

```
   $jasper = new JasperPHP;
    $jasper->process(
        public_path() . '/reports/Faktura.jasper',
        $output,
        array("pdf"),
        array("fID"=>$request->fID),
        Config::get('database.connections.mysql')
    )->output();
```

Where is fID param. in report Faktura and also get error:
Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console.

when try output I get that in output:
[image: output]

TNX.

Comment: whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is be that I didn't install JasperStarter. After that need to settup MYSQL connector. For more info look at:
[Unable to load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622595/unable-to-load-driver-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)