# Unable to load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: php, mysql, database, jdbc, laravel-5

I try to use Jasper to generate report in Laravel. It's work perfect if I didn't use database, if I add database to get data from mysql database he gives me an error "Unable to load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". I install JDBC Connector and  Setup ODBC connection to local mysql server:
[image]

Also I setup CLASSPATH to MySQL connector:
[image: classpath]

Because laravel print me that have some error to generate pdf with database connection I change it to print output command and ran it in terminal and he gives me an error that "Unable to load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", see next picture:
[image]

If you have ANY idea I will be grateful!

Comment: The Connector/J driver has nothing to do with your Connector/ODBC installation. As such it is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of Java applications do not use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, and it looks like jasperstarter is one of them.

Looking at http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/usage.html you need to use the command line option `--jdbc-dir <directory with driver jar(s)>`:

> `--jdbc-dir <dir>`       directory where jdbc driver jars are located. Defaults to ./jdbc

Alternatively, as you indicated in the comments, you can put the driver in the `JasperStarter/jdbc` folder, as that is the default location.

Comment: TNX man! If anybody needs something like that: just copy mysql-connector-java into JasperStarter\jdbc direcory

Comment: @StojanKukrika You're welcome. I added your solution to my answer as well. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No problem. You can add me one up, for team work, to I earn more reputation, if you like  :)